# ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView in Spinner

Tags: android

I try to create list dialog for spinner but I have error "ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView" I created my custum adapter for it

```
public class OrderTypeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;
private final List<String> values;

private class ResourseHolder{
    protected TextView text;
}

public OrderTypeAdapter(Context context, List<String> values) {

    super(context, R.layout.item_list_dialog,values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView;
    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_dialog,parent,false);
        ResourseHolder holder = new ResourseHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ild_main_text_view);
        rowView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        rowView = convertView;
    }

    ResourseHolder holder = (ResourseHolder) rowView.getTag();
    holder.text.setText(values.get(position));

    return rowView;
}
```

}

xml code of item

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/ild_main_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

I set Addapter to spinner by standart way

```
OrderTypeAdapter adapter =new OrderTypeAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            Convert.toList(searchParam.getOrderTypes()));
    orderTypeSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When I click at spinner for show dialog my application crashed, but when I try with ArrayAdapter all was ok. What is the problem here ?

Comment: show the code where you initialized orderTypeSpinner as well

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for

```
 rowView.findViewById(R.id.ild_main_text_view);
```

but inside your layout you have

```
@+id/item_text_view
```

So you should change it accordingly:

```
rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_text_view);
```

Answer (score 0):

in your else condition do

```
holder = (ResourseHolder) rowview.getTag()
```

and initialize rowview with convert view at start

Answer (score 0):

I decided problem with extend BaseAdapter insteed ArrayAdapter :)

Answer (score 0):

you didn't defined getDropDownView in your customized Arrayadapter.spinners need a getdropdown method in array adapter. my recommendation is define a getCustomView method in Arrayadapter. a simple code for example must be like it :

```
public class Adapter1 extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] string1;
    private final String[] stringpic;



    public Adapter1(Activity context, String[] name, String[] pic) {
        super(context, R.layout.row, name);

        this.context = context;
        this.string1 = name;
        this.stringpic = mpic;           
    }


    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }


    public View getCustomView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        TextView txtname = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView);           
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView); 



 // write your statements in here for example
 if (string1[position] != null) {
           txtname.setText(string1[position]);
        }

    return rowView;
}
}
```